# What self-adhesive door sweeps last longer than 1 year?

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

Is there any self-adhesive brand out there that have been shown to last at least one year or longer?

- more context:
  exterior door, in-swing.

Just got a 'duckbrand.com' self-adhesive one. Wood door, inside temp about 70*F, outdoor about 40*F. I pressed firmly but it could barely hold it's own weight and fell off when barely touched.

(Self-adhesive search limitation - It is my father's house and he is VERY adverse to drilling in the door. Honestly, he'd probably opt for a big heating bill instead of drilling. Don't ask me why - these are just the limitations of this situation.)

thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

I always found the ones that have screws to fix them work, don't fall off and last 10 years or more.

Anything with "sticky" falls off after weeks or sometimes months.

Answer (score 0):

For the stick-on sweep to have any hope it must not touch the floor at any point.  If the gap is HUGE but consistent as the door swings open, you can reduce it with a stick-on sweep that never touches the floor.

The usual curmudgeonly approach to this problem is a draft sausage aka door sock.   How delightful it would be if you gave him one ironically hand knitted with power tools on it.  (Image by AI)

[image]